# Horizontally filling nan values into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe, with the data set up as such:

```
df = [
[0, 1, 2, nan, nan, 5, nan, nan],
[nan, 1, 2, 3, nan, nan, 6, nan],
[nan, nan, 3, 4, nan, 6, nan, nan]
 ]

Expected Output: 
df=[
[0, 1, 2, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
[nan, 1, 2, 3, nan, nan, nan, nan],
[nan, nan, 3, 4, nan, 6, nan, nan]
]
```

I am trying to figure out an apply function by row that remove the values and replace them with a nan if numerical values have occurred, then a nan value, essentially removeing the 5 and 6 values in the data.

Thanks!

Comment: can you pls post your expected output?

Comment: IIUC you want to replace with `NaN` all numerical values where previous and next values are `NaN`, is that correct?

Comment: This needs *debugging details*-close vote reason

Comment: Hello thanks for the comments, I posted expected output. And Max, I need to replace values that comes after the first nan value after the first numerical value to be nan

Comment: I'm sorry but, I don't understand your algorithm. You may also want to fix your df: the 3rd row has only 7 elements, the other rows have got 8 elements.

Comment: excuse me about the different lengths, but I solved it posting answer

Comment: It's impossible to understand the question. I would close it.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your meaning, but if you're just trying to replace a given value with nan, you can use np.where

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df==5, np.nan, df))
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by looping through columns (know I thought I wanted to do a row loop but this worked). I determined this by looking at all previous rows, determining if there was a nan, a numerical, then a nan, and if the current column was numerical.

Thanks for all the help!